# JNI:how to call c++ function from Java Native Method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

i am working on some java application in which i am using jni. Well here now i want to call **pure c++ function from JNI method**. well i am doing this as shown as below code. here dll is created but when i am trying run i get the error  **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  Can't find dependent libraries**. i am creating my dll in visual studio. so tell me what i am doing wrong in calling c++ function.

here is code of my .cpp file

```
#include "SensorDetect.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
// Include specific Tools header
#include "Tools.h"
   // Include IO_XRayUSB_MD_VC80 header
#include "IO_XRayUSB.h"

// Include IO_XRayUSB_MD_VC80 library
#pragma message ("Using : IO_XRayUSB_MD_VC80.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "IO_XRayUSB_MD_VC80.lib")

//// Custom user Callback function which is called by IO_XrayUsb when a device is plugged or unplugged
void _stdcall DevicePlugUnplugCallback(XRay_CALLBACK * pCallBackInfo, int nCallBackCount)
{
    if (pCallBackInfo && (nCallBackCount > 0))
    {
        for (int nDeviceIndex = 0; nDeviceIndex < nCallBackCount; nDeviceIndex ++)
        {
            switch(pCallBackInfo[nDeviceIndex].nState)
            {
                case XRAY_USB_PLUGGED_DEVICE :
                    printf("\n=>Callback Device: %s has been Plugged...\n\n", pCallBackInfo[nDeviceIndex].pcDeviceName);
                    break;
                case XRAY_USB_UNPLUGGED_DEVICE :
                    printf("\n=>Callback Device: %s has been Unplugged...\n\n", pCallBackInfo[nDeviceIndex].pcDeviceName);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_sensordetect_SensorDetect_getDevice(JNIEnv * env, jclass cl)
{

     const int nNbMaxDevices = 10;
    char pDeviceList[nNbMaxDevices][260];
    int nDeviceCount = 10;
    XRay_HANDLE hDevice;
    XRay_SENSOR_INFO SensorInfo;


    //int nTriggerMode = GetChoice(1, "Choose Trigger Mode:\t0:XVIS_detection    1:TWI_request_detection");
    char pcBuffer[100];
    int nKey;

        nKey=0;

            int nTriggerMode=nKey;

    try
    {
        // XRay_RegisterCallBackPlugDevice to be notified of device plug/unplug
**//This function call creates problem in loading dll. error:Can't find dependent libraries**
     BOOL bSuccess = XRay_RegisterCallBackPlugDevice(DevicePlugUnplugCallback);    


        //for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < 1; nIndex ++)
            printf("\tFound device : %s\n", pDeviceList[0]);

    }
    catch (...) // catch own CMyException
        {
            //e.ShowReason();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Aside from the UnsatisfiedLinkError, you should try using JNA instead of JNI. It's a lot easier to use and debug.

Comment: @rob Please provide me some good links for JNA tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `IO_XRayUSB_MD_VC80.dll` or one of is dependents is not in one of the directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable, or does not exist in the same directory where your application is running.

To get a list of DLLs on which a DLL depends you can use [`dumpbin.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> dumpbin.exe /DEPENDENTS C:\path\to\IO_XRayUSB_MD_VC80.dll

Comment: Well I am using Netbeans to launch my program and it runs well if just comment that one method which is causing problem
dumpbin.exe  doesn't getting an result any other way to check dependencies

Comment: what do you mean by "dumpbin doesn't get an result"?

Comment: Using dependency walker i get know this 3 dll are creating problem in loading my dll.MSVCR80.DLL,IESHIMS.DLL,GPSVC.DLL. please tell me how should i build my dll what change should i make in creating dll. i am using MSVS2010 to create dll

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify the `-Djava.library.path=C:\path\to\DLLs` option when launching your program, and/or include the DLLs' directories in the Windows `PATH`.

Comment: Well I am using Netbeans  to launch my program and it runs well if just comment that one method which is causing problem.

Comment: @AshishDonvir The one method that uses the DLL that isn't in the path.

Comment: @EJP well i am able to make dll as i had given all the required path in visual studio vc++ project properties. But do i also need to give same set of path in Netbeans also in order to use that dll ?